# Editing touching polygons simultaneously?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, topology

Is there any way - in ArcGIS - to edit touching polygons simultaneously?

More precisely - when I  split one polygon I would like to automatically add a  vertex in the other polygon that shares the edge where the split happened.

[image: So, basicly something like this]

Any way to do that?

Comment: Your definition of "automatically" needs refinement. This is certainly possible, but you'll need to choose a development environment and code the tool yourself.

Comment: Seriously? I was hoping rather for a setting somewhere... I know for a fact Geomedia does have this. Same for Qgis. I find it difficult to believe that ArcGis is missing such a function...

Answer (score 1):

I thought that this may have been possible by creating a [map topology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-topology/creating-a-map-topology.htm) first.

However, when I did that before cutting a polygon equivalent to yours on the left, it did not insert a vertex on the polygon equivalent to yours on the right.

Consequently, if you do not wish to code a tool to do this, and are seeking out-of-the-box functionality you may need to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/) or, as [commented by @SergeNorin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232325/editing-touching-polygons-in-sympathy/233345?noredirect=1#comment363261_233345):

> This is possible with [geodatabase] topology but you have to validate
>   it. After this all missing vertices will be added.

Comment: This is possible with topology but you have to validate it. After this all missing vertices will be added.

Comment: @SergeNorin Maybe with geodatabase topology but it does not seem to be the case for map topology.  Validate topology seems to only apply to geodatabase topology.

Comment: you're right. You can't validate map topology. And with database topology this missing vetices won't be added automatically, only after validating. But at least it's a workaround.

Comment: Did you try calling [ITopologyGraph.Build](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ITopologyGraph_Build.htm), passing it the envelope of the polygon that was just split?  If that works, then it seems like it could be wired to occur _automatically_ via an Editor Extension.